# Calculate length of a cycle, average etc. in a Dataframe with Datetime tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe file that looks like below (imagine so many other rows):

```
    DateTime               hours   uptime   Start_stop  machine_started     Voltage
2022-02-22  07:50:58;269    18,7    43269      221            0               800
2022-02-22  07:50:59;614    18,7    44609      221            0               800
2022-02-22  07:50:59;614    18,7    44609      221            1               800
2022-02-22  07:51:01;915    18,7    46904      221            1               700
2022-02-22  07:51:01;915    18,7    46904      221            1               500
2022-02-22  08:16:20;343    18,7    48523      221            0               800
2022-02-22  08:16:20;638    18,7    48523      221            0               800
2022-02-23  07:51:01;915    18,7    46904      221            1               800
2022-02-23  07:51:03;543    18,7    48523      221            1               1000
2022-02-23  08:16:20;343    18,7    48523      221            0               800
2022-02-23  08:16:20;638    18,7    48523      221            0               800
```

I need a logic to say when the machine is working, from the moment the (machine_started==1) start taking the rows until it ends (machine_started==0) and calculate the average of those rows, standard deviation and the length of that cycle.

I would like to have the Datetime tag that shows the process start time. As you can see for this example I have two times that the process starts.

So in the final file I will see a number of rows which corresponds to the number of cycles in that file.

Unfortunately I can just think of doing one task at a time and also after finding the first cycle I get stuck and cannot count the rows or perform these calculation.

So at the I would like to see something like this:

```
DateTime               Average_Voltage      standard_deviation    length_of_the_cycle  
2022-02-22  07:50:59;614       666                xxx                        YYY
2022-02-23  07:51:01;915       900                xxx                        YYY
```

How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First identify the groups that you are interested in and remove all other rows. To get the groups, we can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html). For the filtering, we need to consider whether the first row starts with `machine_started` 0 or 1. This determines if we want the odd or even numbered groups.

Code for this part:

```
df['grp'] = df['machine_started'].ne(df['machine_started'].shift(1)).cumsum()
start = df['machine_started'].iloc[0]
df = df.loc[(df['grp'] + start) % 2 == 0]
```

Intermediate result:

```
                  DateTime hours  uptime  Start_stop  machine_started  Voltage  grp
2  2022-02-22 07:50:59;614  18,7   44609         221                1      800    2
3  2022-02-22 07:51:01;915  18,7   46904         221                1      700    2
4  2022-02-22 07:51:01;915  18,7   46904         221                1      500    2
7  2022-02-23 07:51:01;915  18,7   46904         221                1      800    4
8  2022-02-23 07:51:03;543  18,7   48523         221                1     1000    4
```

Now, we can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate the information needed. Finally, rename the obtained columns:

```
df = df.groupby('grp').agg({'DateTime': ['first'], 'Voltage': ['mean', 'std', 'count']}).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['DateTime', 'Average_Voltage', 'standard_deviation', 'length_of_the_cycle']
```

Result:

```
                  DateTime  Average_Voltage  standard_deviation  length_of_the_cycle
0  2022-02-22 07:50:59;614       666.666667          152.752523                    3
1  2022-02-23 07:51:01;915       900.000000          141.421356                    2
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution and explanation. I am now trying to use this code and combine it with the rest of my code and I will write back to you. I was trying to do this for days and you did it very nicely!:))

Comment: @fix_my_bug: Happy to help and hope it works out for you. Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the solution to mark the question as solved if it worked :)

Comment: I accepted it since it is working fine but I cannot vote for it since I am a new user. But I will do it as soon as I get the permission. Cheers!